# Highcharter stacked column with series length == 1: Category name is not correct

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I'm trying to draw stacked column chart with series length == 1.
Category name is not correct  (this.category.name). It's not just about labels, I use this.category.name in return. Please help.

```
chart <- highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = c("Apples")) %>%
  hc_add_series(c(5), name = "John") %>%
  hc_add_series(c(3), name = "Jane") %>%
  hc_add_series(c(2), name = "Joe") %>%
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal"))
chart
```

[image]

Comment: It's not just about labels, I use this.category.name in return.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in defining the x axis labels, called `categories` in `highcharter`. I have made other changes to the posted code.

- The main change is to have `categories` as a `list`.
- vectors with just one element, `c("Apple")` or `c(5)`,  were simplified.

And the code becomes:

```
library(highcharter)

chart <- highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = list("Apples")) %>%
  hc_add_series(5, name = "John") %>%
  hc_add_series(3, name = "Jane") %>%
  hc_add_series(2, name = "Joe") %>%
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal"))
chart
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass list instead of vector in categories for hcXaxis:

```
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)

chart <- highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = list("Apples")) %>%
  hc_add_series(c(5), name = "John") %>%
  hc_add_series(c(3), name = "Jane") %>%
  hc_add_series(c(2), name = "Joe") %>%
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal"))
chart
```